# Update multiple columns performance of DB on java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

A development environments:

- Java 14.0.2(latest)
- SQLite 3.30.1
- On MacOS
- using Eclipse IDE

I use in-memory DB and there are hundreds of thousands items(about 800,000 items) in a table of DB file.
I just use for-loop one by one to update columns.
But, it's too slow.
I know a for-loop is inefficient.

A value and conditions below codes is not from DB.
It's just calculated values by some codes.

```
for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    update(array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i], array5[i], array6[i], valueArray[i]);
}

public void update(int condition1, String condition2, int condition3, int condition4, String condition5, int condition6, int value) {
        try (PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                String query = "UPDATE table\n"
                        + "SET value = ?\n"
                        + "WHERE condition1 = ?\n"
                        + "AND condition2 = ?\n"
                        + "AND condition3 = ?\n"
                        + "AND condition4 = ?\n"
                        + "AND condition5 = ?\n"
                        + "AND condition6 = ?\n";
                
                pst.setInt(1, value);
                pst.setString(2, condition1);
                pst.setInt(3, condition2);
                pst.setInt(4, condition3);
                pst.setString(5, condition4);
                pst.setInt(6, condition5);
                pst.setInt(7, condition6);
                
                pst.execute();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I tunning the codes?

Comment: Can't you just do a single `UPDATE` that affects all rows in one statement? Your question does not provide enough context to know whether that is an option or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can't use single UPDATE SET query because the condition and values will be calculated by some codes, not from DB. Unfortunately, I should use code like upper.

Answer (score 0):

The loop itself is not a problem, problematic are round-trips involved in updating each row separately. Performance can be improved by using batch updates:

```
try(PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        pst.setInt(1, valueArray[i]);
        pst.setString(2, array1[i]);
        pst.setInt(3, array2[i]);
        pst.setInt(4, array3[i]);
        pst.setString(5, array4[i]);
        pst.setInt(6, array5[i]);
        pst.setInt(7, array6[i]);
        // addBatch instead of execute
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    // Finally execute the whole batch
    int[] affectedRows = pst.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. However, I couldn't get the efficient performance by using batch methods of PreparedStatement.